# How to fix React Native Navigation with Expo - Module 'react-native-gesture-handler' does not exist in Haste module map

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I am trying to add react-navigation to my Expo react-native application. I already made a mistake by installing react-native-gesture-handler, as it was included in the Expo library. I tried to fix this by removing the gesture handler in my package.json file and deleting the node modules and the package.lock file then running npm install again. This solution fixed a test project with a similar issue, however, this one still persists.

Here is my only react-native-gesture handler dependencies.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j361xml8irsf8xg/Screen%20Shot%202019-04-11%20at%207.47.31%20PM.png?dl=0

And here is a link to what my react native screen is giving me

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9xjzjliwhjwbft/IMG_AFC01F6D20DA-1.jpg?dl=0

Module 'react-native-gesture-handler' does not exist in the haste module map? Any idea how to fix this issue would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete your node_modules and package-lock.json or yarn.lock and run npm install or yarn again. After that run `expo start -c` to clear the cache for the packager and your problem will be resolved, most likely.